# PDF Javascript thisfield action

Tags: pdf

Have following coding:
   this.field("Text4").value="888.88";

BUT Text4 is never changed (using blur and Mouse Up/Down and onFocus just to try everything).

PDF is running under WondersharePDFelement
I am VERY new at this (as you probably guessed already).
Any help/clues are Greatly appreciated...Jack

Answer (score 1):

You may have a look at the Acrobat JavaScript documentation.

There you would find that accessing a field uses the `getField()` method.